# The radius of the track.

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A racing car completes $5$ rounds of circle in $2$ mins . It has uniform centripetal acceleration $\pi^2 t^{-2}$ then the radius of circle is?. I asked it on physics $SE$ but I dont know how to ask questions there. So My try I let $\alpha=\pi^2$ so $a=\pi^2r$ also $a=\frac{v^2}{r}$ so $v=\pi.R$ also it covers $10\pi$ in $120$s . But don't know how to calculate the radius from it.

Comment: How is the acceleration uniform if it is changing with time?

Comment: Radius $r$. 5 circuits in 2 min means $v=10\pi r/120$, so acceleration is $\frac{v^2}{r}=\pi^2$, so $r=144$.

Comment: I don't know physics.  So I don't know what centripetal acceleration is or how to calculate it.  But the car covers 10 pi in 2 minutes and 5 rounds in 2 minutes, then the circumference of the circle is 2 pi and therefore it's radius is 1.  Um, what are your units of distance? And is t measured in minutes or time?

Comment: How do you get from $a = \pi t^{-2}$ to $a = \pi^2$ to $a=\pi^2 r$?  If we can pin down $a$, then  $\frac {v^2}{r} = a, v = \sqrt{ar}, \frac {10\pi r}{120} = \sqrt{ar}.$  And that should be enough information to find $r.$

Comment: @fleablood this assumes *constant speed* so zero acceleration. Here the car accelerates...

Comment: What is alpha? <>

Comment: It's the angular acceleration. But if you have your own questions re: physics, you should perhaps ask them yourself. @fleablood

Comment: Jacks wasted life t^-2 should be a unit of measure, and not a variable.  This question needs some units specified.  t^-2 should be something like m/sec^2.

Comment: I'm trying to help with the math, not the physics.  If he got v=pi unit/min. Then radius is 1/5 unit, but if the car covered 10 pi units in 2 minutes v= 5 pi and radius is 1 unit.  The question needs some unit clarification.  It doesn't need any physics clarification.  And as this is a math board all physics are the responsibility of the questioner, not the answerer.

Comment: @gt6989b *Angular* acceleration; not linear acceleration.  The car is on a circular track so it does *not* have constant *velocity*.

Comment: I don't see how you get $a = \pi^2 r$.  But if so then $v = \pi r$ not $\pi$... which doesn't make any sense as that is a distance with no reference to any units of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\pi^2 t^{-2}$ need clarification as to what units these are in.

I am going to assume units are seconds and meters and so

Angular momementum = $\pi^2 m/sec^2 = v^2/r$

Length of lap = Circumference = $2 \pi r$.

$120sec*v = 5*(2\pi r)$ so $v = \frac{\pi}{12} r/sec$.

So $am = \pi^2 m/sec^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{144}r^2/sec^2*r= \frac{\pi^2}{144}r/sec^2$

So $r = \frac{144\pi^2 m*sec^2}{\pi^2*sec^2} = 144 m$.

That is if the units are meters and seconds, which was never specified.

Comment: Yes sir it's unit $t^{-2}$ sorry next time if I such question I'll give all the required definitions.